# Draw circle with random color on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Hi I try to draw a ball with a random color on the canvas with a function, but it wont work. How can I fix it that the syntax is at `ctx.fillStyle = 'JSON.stringify(getRandomElement(circles))';` right?

> Uncaught ReferenceError: yellow is not defined

```
    function drawcircles() {
function getRandomElement(array) {
  if (array.length == 0) {
    return undefined;
  }
  return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
}

var circles = [
  yellow,
  red,  
  blue
];

ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(ballx * 108, canvasHeight / 2, x*5, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
      ctx.fillStyle = 'JSON.stringify(getRandomElement(circles))';
      ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath;

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you can see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_fillstyle.asp) (one of the many references for this) the fill style color must be declared as HEX.

You have to turn your color in that notation to run your code

- Yellow is #FFFF00;
- Red is #FF0000;
- Blue is #0000FF;

Your array will become:

```
var circles = [
  '#FFFF00',
  '#FF0000',  
  '#0000FF'
];
```

Anyway your array was wrong also because you didn't wrap the values that are strings in single or double quotes since these are strings and not js variables

Comment: thanks for your help. The error message is away but the circle wont become drawed :/

Comment: Oh, I dont defined the function. I only copied into a normal draw function in a game loop.

Comment: try changing      `ctx.fillStyle = 'JSON.stringify(getRandomElement(circles))';` to       `ctx.fillStyle = JSON.stringify(getRandomElement(circles));` without quotes

Comment: No one, thats the curious

Comment: That's not true, `ctx.fillStyle()` does accept colors as `rgba()`or `rgb()` or `hsl()` values.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `yellow`, `red` and `blue` in the array `circles` are variables, and they have not been defined. So you could a) put the HEX codes in those variables, or b) just replace those with the HEX codes.

a) e.g.

```
var yellow = "#ffff00";  //first put the code for yellow in the variable
var circles = [yellow]   //then put that variable in the list
```

b) e.g.

```
var circles = ["#ffff00"];  //put the HEX code directly in the array
```

Answer (score 1):

For interest's sake. You can generate a random hex color with this script:

`var color = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);`

Some more info on why this works [here](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/random-hex-color-code-snippets/).

Answer (score -1):

My bad.

Messed up tabbing confused me.